# How to use CalendarView.YearViewDrawDayBackground event in Schedule Control Single User?

Tags: vb.net, schedule, dotnetbar

How to use `CalendarView.YearViewDrawDayBackground` event in Schedule Control Single User?

I would like to draw the cells background (in `YearView`) to the type of associated appointment.

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".